# module can't add in zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am a new zend framework user. I’ve developed one module and want to add to existing project but whenever wants to add module I got below errors:

```
Message: Role 'product:GUEST' not found
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/start/dashboard/library/Zend/Acl.php(837): Zend_Acl_Role_Registry->get('product:GUEST')
#1 /var/www/start/dashboard/library/pldashboard/Controller/Plugin/AccessControl.php(82): Zend_Acl->isAllowed('product:GUEST', NULL, 'index')
#2 /var/www/start/dashboard/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php(309): Pidashboard_Controller_Plugin_AccessControl->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 /var/www/start/dashboard/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(941): Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /var/www/start/dashboard/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#5 /var/www/start/dashboard/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#6 /var/www/start/dashboard/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#7 {main}
Request Parameters:
array (
  'module' => 'product',
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
)
```

My website's structure is:

[image]

```
#Application/
    |--Bootstrap.php
    |--#modules
    |----#dashboard
    |------Bootstrap.php
    |------controllers
    |------view
    |------Models
    |----#default
    |------Bootstarp.php
    |------#controllers
    |------#view
```

I have not placed everything, but the most important is here. This works fine and whenever I want to add new module like transactionview and getting error (above). i don't know what i will do in these situations and also i don't have enough knowledge about configurations

Comment: Have you configured ACL?

Comment: honestly i am very new in zend framework..i have no idea about ACL:(
how to configure ACL ?

Comment: here is the my Acl.php file for your review http://www.filedropper.com/acl...could you please check what i did wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Role "product:GUEST" in your [ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.introduction.html) (check file: /var/www/start/dashboard/library/pldashboard/Controller/Plugin/AccessControl.php ) and it tries to check permissions for role "(82): Zend_Acl->isAllowed('product:GUEST', NULL, 'index')".

There is probably ACL config file in `Application/configs` or table in DB where you can add roles and permissions.